# Retrieving an object's ID

Tags: c#, linq

I have written the following Query to retrieve some object's ID. If there are objects in the list that have a larger `numbinbatch` than the `saveditems` number in the batch, then it should take that. If not, then it should take the first number from the lower number in batches.

I am wondering if this could be shortened. I'd also like to know if my query is bad for performance and how it can be improved.

```
int NextItemID = 0;
var items =
    rep.FindWhere(i => i.ID == itemID)
    .Select(i => i.Batch)
    .SelectMany(b => b.Items);

    var savedItem = items.First(i => i.ID == itemID);
    var unsavedItems = items.Where(i => i.StatusID == (short) ItemStatus.Pending);

    var higherNumInBatch = unsavedItems.Where(i => i.NumInBatch > savedItem.NumInBatch).OrderBy(i=>i.NumInBatch);
    var lowerNumInBatch = unsavedItems.Where(i => i.NumInBatch < savedItem.NumInBatch).OrderBy(i=>i.NumInBatch);

    if (higherNumInBatch.Any())
    {
       NextItemID = (int)higherNumInBatch.Take(1).First().ID;
    }
    else
    {
       NextItemID = (int)lowerNumInBatch.Take(1).First().ID;
    }

    return NextItemID;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be shorter, it takes less selects, and may runs at SQL server side

```
return rep.FindWhere(i => i.ID == itemID)
          .SelectMany(i => i.Batch.Items)
          .Where(i => i.StatusID == (short) ItemStatus.Pending)
          .MaxBy(i => i.NumInBatch).ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MaxBy()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914198/298754), which is taken from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

```
var items = rep.FindWhere(i => i.ID == itemID)
               .Select(i => i.Batch)
               .SelectMany(b => b.Items);

var NextItem = items.Where(i => i.StatusID == (short) ItemStatus.Pending)
                    .MaxBy(i => i.NumInBatch);

return NextItem.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you certainly can/should do is this:

```
var higherNumInBatch = unsavedItems.Where(i => i.NumInBatch > savedItem.NumInBatch).OrderBy(i=>i.NumInBatch);

if (higherNumInBatch.Any())
{
    NextItemID = (int)higherNumInBatch.Take(1).First().ID;
}
else
{
    var lowerNumInBatch = unsavedItems.Where(i => i.NumInBatch < savedItem.NumInBatch).OrderBy(i=>i.NumInBatch);
    NextItemID = (int)lowerNumInBatch.Take(1).First().ID;
}
```

This way you'll only fetch the lower numbers in the batch *only* if there is no higher one. In your case you're always getting both lists which is not always necessary.

Comment: What if unsavedItems is empty.  Take(1).First() will fail.  Also using .Any() on highNumberInBatch and then .Take() potentially enumerates the list twice.  Consider using ToList() first.

Comment: You're right, there should be an extry check to see if 'unsavedItems' has any items at all. :)